# Trying to center an image within a flex item using flexbox. What's going on here?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to center an image in the fixed `nav` menu of a flex item.
I've tried using the `justify-content: center;` command, but I don't think it did anything.

Below is the CSS and abbreviated HTML. Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XmQQgb

#### CSS:

```
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

nav { 
  flex: 0 0 300px;
  background: gray;
}
.nav-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0;
}

section {
  flex: 1 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.navImage {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <img class="navImage" width="100" height="100" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/56/Run.svg">

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <blockquote><i>Please, make me fixed!</i></blockquote>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero.</p>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The width of your `nav` element is 300px.

```
nav { 
    flex: 0 0 300px;
    background: gray;
}
```

The width of your `.nav-wrapper` element (the child of `nav`) is undefined.

```
.nav-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Because `.nav-wrapper` has `position: fixed` it is taken out of the [normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#normal-flow) of the document and has a default width of 0, which will expand only enough to wrap content.

As the width of `.nav-wrapper` is limited to the width of the content, centering occurs within this limited space. If you add a border around `.nav-wrapper`, you'll see that the image is actually perfectly centered... *within the available width*.

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYVqwm)

To center the image along the full width of the `nav` column you could specify a width for `.nav-wrapper` equal to the width of `nav`.

Try this:

```
.nav-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px; /* new */
}
```

So essentially you were almost there. You just needed one more line of code.

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GpLaGV)

---

*Addressing the `justify-content` issue...*

#### Defining the Flex Items

You've set the outer container (`.wrapper`) to `display: flex`, which makes it a [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers).

This converts the child elements of `.wrapper` into [flex items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items). In other words, `nav` and `section` become flex items.

Note that the descendents of a flex container beyond the children are *not* flex items and flex properties don't apply to them. Hence, any flex code added to `.nav-wrapper` or `.navImage` would be ignored, unless their parents became flex containers.

#### justify-content

The [`justify-content`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33856609/3597276) property won't work in your current code for these reasons:

1. The `img` element is not a flex item (as described above), so flex properties won't apply to it.
2. Even if you make the `img` parent (`.nav-wrapper`) into a flex container, `justify-content` may not be a good solution because `img` has two siblings: `ul` and `blockquote`, and all three would be centered with `justify-content`.
3. If you wanted to make `img` (and its siblings) flex items, then it may be more efficient to use a column-direction, not a row-direction, flex container. In this case, you wouldn't use `justify-content` for horizontal centering. You would need to use `align-items` or `align-self`. [Learn more about the main axis, the cross axis and alignment properties.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32551291/3597276)

Comment: Is it possible to do the same if the `nav` flex container is set to: `flex: 1 6 20%` as shown in the [Holy Grail Layout example from mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes#Holy_Grail_Layout_example), without the header/footer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Mozilla Holy Grail Layout. Please provide a demo or a separate question and I'll be happy to review it.